# C# ICommand / RelayCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, icommand, relaycommand

I recently started learning WPF (with MVVM pattern). I have got a question about `ICommand` implementation...

```
private ICommand _confirmOptionCommand;

public ICommand ConfirmOptionCommand
{
   get
   {
      if (_confirmOptionCommand == null)
      {
        _confirmOptionCommand = new RelayCommand(ConfirmOptionMethod);
      }
      return _confirmOptionCommand;
   }
}

private void ConfirmOptionMethod() { ... }
```

But I can write like this:

```
private RelayCommand _confirmOptionCommand;

public RelayCommand ConfirmOptionCommand { ... }

private void ConfirmOptionMethod() { ... }
```

What advantages `ICommand` has got? Or what is the difference between them?

Comment: ``ICommand`` is interface which ``RelayCommand`` implementes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RelayCommand` `is` an `ICommand`, just a different implementation which allows you to call a delegate when the command is executed.

When you write `ICommand` instead of `RelayCommand` as the variable type, you still have to point to an `ICommand` object. But you only have access to the `ICommand` interface. If you want other aspects which the object have, you need the derived class reference. In our case, it's a `RelayCommand` reference..

Here's how a `RelayCommand` may look like (Not gonna compile, but you get it):

```
public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand {
    private Action<T> action;

    public RelayCommand(T action){
        this.action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(obj param){
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(obj param){
        this.action((T)param);
    }

    public CanExecuteEventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

}
```

There are other types of `ICommand` such as `RoutedUICommand` which works with event handlers.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I thought it was so, but now you dispelled doubts :)

Comment: @xitryuga, please accept the answer if it answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer to your Question would be to make it **loosely coupled**

On saying that, a loosely-coupled class(`ICommand`) can be consumed and tested independently of other concrete classes(`RelayCommand`).

Consider if you want to change `RelayCommand` to some other delegating command in future(like `DelegateCommand`) to invoke, in this case it will take more time and effort to replace all the consumers were you have used the concrete class reference(`RelayCommand`).

On using the `ICommand` on client while consuming provides a way to switch to any concrete class that implements `ICommand` without any changes in client(consumers).